# Backbone model change and view render update

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, express, requirejs

I have an express app with session in the back end, and in the front I have Backbone+RequireJS. My problem is with the session Model I have, and the change event that triggers the render method on the views.

So:

1. The app has a Home view, that has a listener to the "change" event of the Session Model, and runs the "render" method.
2. An users with no credentials go into a public page from the home, let's say to /about
3. In there, the user logins from the header that has a login form (user/password).
4. Because of the listener in item 1, the container element gets an updated with the new home content, but the user is still in /about.

So, the question is: How do I avoid this bad behavior, so the views only listen to events if the correct route is active?

**A code example:**

```
"use strict";

var SessionModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var sessionModel = new SessionModel();

var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(sessionModel, "change", this.render);
    },
    render: function() {
        // updates the main container element
    }
});

var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    "": "home",
    "about": "about"
});

var appRouter = new AppRouter();

appRouter.on("route", function() {
    sessionModel.fetch(); // Updates session model on every route change
});

appRouter.on("route:home", function() {
    var homeView = new HomeView();
    homeView.render();
});
```

Comment: Isn't the problem really that the user on `/about` but `HomeView` still exists? Normally you'd destroy the old view and throw up a new one when switching from `/` to `/about`.

Comment: can you explain why you need to listen to a `sessionModel` change in a particular view ? Wouldn't it should be in a `Router` `initialize` function.

Comment: I'll try the destroy solution, because I need the sessionModel to exist at any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem:

```
sessionModel.on("change", function () {
    Backbone.history.loadUrl();
}).fetch();
```

With this we trigger the correct route and render again without adding listeners to the views.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for an expecific attribute instead of listen for every kind of change.

```
this.bind("change:SomeExpecificThing", doEspecificThing)
```

Comment: With the current structure, the change still triggers the "render" method of the HomeView and replaces the content of the main container. The problem is not with the property beeing change, it's with the event listeners.